# Calendar UI is not opening on Android using react-native-add-calendar-event

Tags: android, react-native

Below is the source code I have used in my project, functionality works as expected while in debug mode on android but once it is released nothing happens.

Source Code

```
    var startDateNew = Moment.utc(getFormattedDate(`${this.props.start_date_timestamp}
    ${this.props.start_time.split(" ")[0]}`, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]"));
    const eventConfig = {
    title: this.props.title,
    startDate: startDateNew
    // and other options
    };


    Analytics.trackEvent("Start Date As per YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z] " + startDateNew)

    AddCalendarEvent.presentEventCreatingDialog(eventConfig)
        .then((eventInfo: { calendarItemIdentifier: string, eventIdentifier: string }) => {
            Analytics.trackEvent("Calender Success" + JSON.stringify(eventInfo))
        })
        .catch((error: string) => {
            Analytics.trackEvent("Calender Error" + JSON.stringify(error))
        });
```

Error Logged on appcenter

> {"line":343,"column":12139,"sourceURL":"index.android.bundle"}

Android Studio Logcat Error is as below

> I/ReactNativeJS: { [TypeError: [object Object],[object Object] is not
>   iterable!]
>         line: 87479,
>         column: 89,
>         sourceURL: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false'
>   }

NPM packages installed as below

> "react-native-add-calendar-event": "2.1.0", "react-native": "0.57.7",

Comment: Have you linked the package with react-native link {package_name}

Comment: yes, the package is linked

Comment: what you values are you getting when you print this.props.start_date_timestamp and this.props.start_time

Comment: those values are as expected, I tried removing stardate the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved, by upgrading the react-native version from 57.3 to 59.9